# Azure DevOps (TFS) dashboard test start date

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops, dashboard

I want to know if there is any possibility to add on an Azure DevOps(TFS) dashboard the start time of the tests.

Currently I have a pie chart with all the test runned over night,(passed, fail and not run) and I want to know if there is any possibility to add the time when the test were executed on this dashboard.

Thank you.

Comment: Which widget do you use? Do you use `Chart for Test Plans`?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes I use Chart for Test Plans

Comment: From what i saw Test Results Trend (Advanced) is used for TFS pipelines. I run my tests from Jenkins and I update only the state of the test (failed, passed, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own widget, based on a custom query, and then add the widget to your dashboard. See more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

If you run tests from Build or Release Pipeline, you may try `Test Results Trend (Advanced)` widget, with the Test Results Trend (Advanced) widget, you can track the test quality of your pipelines over time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-test-results-trend?view=azure-devops

Comment: Is `Test Results Trend (Advanced)` widget helpful?

Comment: From what i saw Test Results Trend (Advanced) is used for TFS pipelines. I run my tests from Jenkins and I update only the state of the test (failed, passed, etc).